# Style Data in a gridview which dynamically generates the columns

Tags: wpf, gridview, styles

I have built a dynamic gridview using the following code

```
 grdVariants.Columns.Clear();
 int i = 0;
 foreach (DataColumn column in options.Columns)
 {
     grdVariants.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
     {
         Header = column.ColumnName,
         DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", i++))
     });
 }
```

This will dynamically generate my columns at runtime, I then bind the data using

```
lstVariantsGrid.DataContext = options;
lstVariantsGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

This all works great and shows the data in the correct columns etc, the only issue i have is that I can't style the rows like I would in xaml as it is all an unknown quantity until runtime. Can anyone offer some advice on how I might go about doing this?

One of the biggest problems I have is that one of the columns needs to display the image rather than just the path which it currently shows, as well as fiddling with fonts and colors etc.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a datatemplate which you can create in xaml and load in code behind and then set to the CellTemplate property of the GridViewColumn.